# jQuery Selector as Function Parameter

Tags: jquery, oop

In the following code I attempt to pass a jQuery listView selector to the function "makeObject" as a parameter. The problem I'm having is that the code doesn't recognize the .listview method of the selector in the function "createList".

I'd like a solution that does simply pass in a string and reconstruct the selector inside 
the called function.

```
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
        function Object() {
            this.selector;
            this.createList;
        }

        function makeObject(selector) {
            var result = new Object();
            result.selector = selector;
            result.createList = createList;

            return result;
        }

        function createList() {
            this.selector.append("<li>list item 1</li>");
            this.selector.append("<li>list item 2</li>");
            this.selector.append("<li>list item 3</li>");
            this.selector.listview("refresh");
        }

        var selectorParam = $("#testList");
        var testObject = makeObject(selectorParam);
        testObject.createList();
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul id="testList" data-role="listview"></ul>
</body>
```

Comment: You don't really want to overwrite `Object`

Comment: Esailija, I'm not sure what you mean could you elaborate?

Comment: Speransky Danil, the listview function is a built in to selected listView elements.

Answer (score 2):

Don't you just want to rather do this:

```
    $("#testList").append('<li>item 3</li>')
```

Or

```
    function makeObject(selector) {
         $(selector).append('<li>item 3</li>')
    }
```

Comment: I'm looking to avoid the first method you suggest because I want this code to be re-useable for listViews associated with different selectors. As far as I can tell the second suggestion is the same as passing in a string and constructing the selector in the called function, which I'm also hoping to avoid.

Comment: The second solution would be the one to go for but change it to be able to pass in listitems. I've added this jsfiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jjay225/Lk8C5/) for you to look it. It is totally reusable. This solution takes into account you already have an unordered list in your html as per your html in your question. Hope that helps